# Getting the list of child processes, run by a parent process in Linux

Tags: linux, process, parent-child

I would like to determine which processes has been called by a parent process (or maybe get a "stack" or tree of processes caused hierarchically).

Unfortunately it's quite difficult to determine PIDs, GPIDs and PPIDs "on fly" because processes terminate too quickly. May be such information can be found out in system logs?

I use RHEL 6.4.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you run your program with strace(1)? It can output this information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `f` option of the `ps` command will help. Try:

```
ps afx
```

This will show all processes and will visualize parent -> child relations in the console.

Comment: Thanks for good advice, but my parent process runs less than 1 second, therefore it's physically impossible to open another terminal at the moment and run this command to get the tree.

Comment: try `strace -f 2>&1` it will show you system calls made by a process and its child processes - recursively. You might grep the output for `fork|exec.*`

Answer (score 0):

Run your program under `strace -f -o strace-log.txt <myprogram>`, looking for `fork`, `execve`, and `clone`.